# Powershell script unable to send to multiple recipients

Tags: email, powershell, smtp

I'm using a powershell script that will create an HTML report of disk space and send it as an email.  Unfortunately I'm unable to get the script to send to more than one email recipient.  The script I'm using can be found here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6e935887-6b30-4654-b977-6f5d289f3a63

Here are the relevant parts of the script...

```
$freeSpaceFileName = "FreeSpace.htm" 
$serverlist = "C:\sl.txt" 
$warning = 90 
$critical = 75 
New-Item -ItemType file $freeSpaceFileName -Force 

Function sendEmail 
{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
$smtp.send($msg) 
} 

$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') 
$recipients = "to1@email.com", "to2@email.com"
sendEmail from@email.mail $recipients "Disk Space Report - $Date" smtp.server $freeSpaceFileName
```

I'm getting the following error

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "4" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e
-mail address."
At E:\DiskSpaceReport.ps1:129 char:18
+ $msg = New-Object <<<<  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MailMessage constructor you are using only takes one email address. See the MSDN documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0.aspx

You should try using `Send-MailMessage` instead because it's `-To` parameter accepts an array of addresses

`Send-MailMessage -from from@email.mail -To $recipients -Subject "Disk Space Report - $Date" -smptServer smtp.server -Attachments $freeSpaceFileName`

Note: Send-MailMessage was introduced in PowerShell v2.0 so that's why there are still examples that use other commands. If you need to use v1.0, then I will update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

There are two methods to send emails using PowerShell:

1. For the **`Send-MailMessage`** method (Introduced in PowerShell Version 2):

   `$to = "to1@email.com", "to2@email.com"`
2. For the **`System.Net.Mail`** method (Works from PowerShell Version 1):

   `$msg.To.Add("to1@email.com")`

   `$msg.To.Add("to2@email.com")`

Answer (score 6):

With `System.Net.Mail` you can also do this in one line. Just be sure to add the parentheses and all recipients comma-separated within a single string:

```
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@email.com","to@email1.com,to@email2.com","Any subject,"Any message body")
```

This also works for RFC-822 formatted e-mail addresses:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("Sender <from@email.com>","Rcpt1 <to@email1.com>,Rcpt2 <to@email2.com>","Any subject,"Any message body")
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MailMessage constructor had been fixed by Microsoft as it accepts multiple recipients, separated by comma character (",") according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Mail_MailMessage__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_

> to String - A String that contains the addresses of the recipients of the email message. Multiple email addresses must be separated with a comma character (",").

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Function sendEmail 
{ param($from,[string[]]$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$msg.from =$from

foreach($a in $to)
{
   $msg.to.Add($a)
}

$msg.Subject= $subject
$msg.Body = $body 
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
$smtp.send($msg) 
} 

sendemail  -from from@email.mail -to $recipients -smtphost smtp.server -subject "Disk Space Report - $Date" -htmlFileName  $freeSpaceFileName
```

Comment: I've tried two different email addresses.  When I set $recipients to just one of either address it works.  However once I combine them both in the $Recipients list it fails.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy, yes.. I had post a new solution! On powershell v3.0 I had no error, but email to second recipient was never send. This way the $msg.to is right populated.

Comment: @CB. Is there any update on this? I am currently facing the same problem, it only send the email to one of the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using send-mailmessage in powershell instead of defining your own function.  My guess is you have a type mismatch on one of your parameters.